# Sharing game results with LibGdx

Tags: android-studio, libgdx

I would like to share game results (image) such that when i click on the share button, [share link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdKrm.png) will appear on the phone.

Answer (score 0):

For sharing text, below you can find a good example, where you can share text with a specific number if you would!

For **JAVA** check the below code.

```
String shareMsg = "your result share link or text";

Intent share = new Intent();
share.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("text/plain");
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareMsg);

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Select an action"));
```

For **Kotlin** check the below code.

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
intent.type = "text/plain"
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareMsg)
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select an action"))
```

> Note:- The above example is sharing text or link. Not use for sharing
>   a document. If you want to share document then you have to change the
>   **Intent.EXTRA_STREAM**. Using **Intent.EXTRA_TEXT** you can share text or message.

Comment: I am having some trouble integrating it with LibGdx. May i know how may i integrate android native code with libgdx?